# How to turn it off the snap button and ok button in camera by android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-camera

I currently require to design a camera function for android version 4 (Kitkat), but i notice that there is snap picture button and ok button in the camera as picture below:

[image]   [image]

How to make it disappear and user just touch on screen it can snap the picture without the button, and the picture will directly save without need of pressing ok button.

Anyone can share me the ideas, I very need you guys help because suffer this for long time already, thanks.

Comment: If you are using `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`, you cannot control the UI of the user's chosen camera app. If you are writing your own camera app, then you put those buttons there yourself and can get rid of them as you see fit.

Comment: Hi, can recommend the documentation on writing the camera app?
I found that the camera2 only support android api level 21 and above

Comment: The [documentation covers the original `Camera` API](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/cameradirect.html), though in reality it is much more complicated than they suggest. I recommend using a library that hides some of the complexity, such as Fotoapparat or CameraKit-Android.

Comment: This two can let me do edition on the buttons right?

Comment: Because my end user is visually impared so the button and the step should be remove

Comment: "This two can let me do edition on the buttons right?" -- they have no buttons. They have no UI, other than a camera preview.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166476/discussion-between-shi-jie-tio-and-commonsware).